# Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Advance Past Login Screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm

I am not sure what caused my current issue but I had recently installed a displaylink driver for a secondary Asus MB186B monitor connected via USB 3. After rebooting this worked fine. I was messing with some things trying to get nightmode working, then installed brightnessctl. Well at that point my entire system got hung up, gnome-shell was pegged at 100% and I was forced to hard restart. Thats when my problems started.

From that point on I cannot advanced past the login screen. This is a bit different than the login loop problem I've read about, but could be similiar, though I have tried much of those fixes with the nvidia drivers and what not. LightDM (what I use) will accept the login, but just sit there. Something similar happens with Gdm3 when I try that display manager. I'm quite perplexed and I can't seem to find anything of note in ~/.xsession-errors

The system has an NVIDIA GM107M [GeFoce GTX 860M]. I've been running 18.04 for at least 6 months now.  This laptop has run fine for 4 years and through several upgrades. Worst, I work off this system and will be unable to work in the morning unless I get this thing resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Several months running without issue and now can't pass login screen. I created a new user and switched to lightdm and it logins fine. 
Sorry to post this comment as an answer, but I have not enough points to do it properly.

EDIT:
As creating a new user worked for me, I did the following workaround:

I made a backup of my home folder, then removed my user and created it once again.
The login worked and now I am copying back folder by folder from the original home folder (I went back to using gdm3 BTW).

It's a bit painstaking, but all the previous installed packages are still there and machine-wide configs are preserved.

Hope this works for you.